# Error of conversion when I create new Object

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, instance

I'm having various error in the instances of new objects. It's the first time I'm programming in c++ so I don't know something, but I really don't know what I miss. Here are some examples of my code and related errors.

```
    Edge newEdge;
    newEdge = new Edge(vertex2, neighbors(vertex1));  // create a new edge without weight
```

The error risen is:

```
invalid conversion from `Edge*' to `int' 
initializing argument 1 of `Edge::Edge(int, Edge*, unsigned int)'
```

and the constructor is

```
public: Edge(int nextVertex = 0, Edge* ptr = NULL, unsigned int weight = 1):nextVertex(nextVertex),
                                                                           next(ptr),
                                                                           weight(weight){};
```

And similar for other classes:

```
PriorityQueue queue = new PriorityQueue();
```

error:

```
conversion from `PriorityQueue*' to non-scalar type `PriorityQueue' requested
```

code:

```
VertexPriority aux;
```

error:

```
no matching function for call to `VertexPriority::VertexPriority()'
```

and for last

```
ShortestPath shortp = new ShortestPath(graph);
```

error:

```
conversion from `ShortestPath*' to non-scalar type `ShortestPath' requested
```

There is an other error that I think I bounded to the provious ones, because It's an instance and the error is similar, here is the code:

```
queue.insert(new VertexPriority(vertex1, 0));
```

and the error is:

```
no matching function for call to `PriorityQueue::insert(VertexPriority*)' 
candidates are: void PriorityQueue::insert(VertexPriority)
```

the constructor of the object is

```
VertexPriority(int vertex, unsigned int priority):vertex(vertex),
                                                        priority(priority){};
```

and the method insert takes a vertex for argument: `void insert(VertexPriority vertex);`

What I miss in my code?

Comment: You missed that this isn't Java or C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is not Java, you don't use `new` when creating normal, non-pointer, objects.

So it's only

```
newEdge = Edge(vertex2, neighbors(vertex1));
```

This causes the copy-assignment operator to be invoked, so you better have one if there's any complex data in the object. See e.g. [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: ok thank you! In effect I came from java and this is my frist c++ program

Comment: the problem that persists is the third one: VertexPriority aux;
how to fix it?

Comment: @giacomotb The same way, don't use `new`.

Comment: in this case I'm not using new, I'm doing 
VertexPriority aux;
[...]
aux = queue.top();

Comment: @giacomotb Okay, I'm mixing all your different things together. If you declare a constructor for `VertexPriority`, any what so ever, the compiler will not generate a default constructor. So you have to make your own default constructor, which the compiler says there is none.

Comment: my constructor is
VertexPriority(int vertex, unsigned int priority):vertex(vertex),                                                       priority(priority){};
How should I create the other one?

Comment: @giacomotb Just add another one, one without arguments. If you don't know anything about default constructors I suggest you start read some very basic tutorials.

Comment: @giacomotb You need a decent text on C++. The move from Java or C# (or any other reference-based language) is a bump. There is a learning curve to this, and as painful as it is, you'll have to go through it (though it ma not be as bad as you think). Ex: Shortly you're going to discover how what seems identical in code for Java actually makes object *copies* in C++.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to have a course on coursera but not everything is explained so well, thank you for the suggestions!